# Php tracking own location gives a randomized IP

Tags: php, maps, leaflet

[image: Map error]

-- Please scroll down to where I marked the **PHP** --

To explain in better detail.

I made a [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) map and in that map I want to load my own location.

Here's my code for that in Javascript, but this is out of question like [@Pocketsand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860663/pocketsand) and I already discussed. So then scroll down to the PHP code and see if you can get the IP address through the browser.

```
$part_content = "<div id=\"mapid\"></div>";

//.setView([".$longitude.", ".$latitude."], ".$zoom_factor.");

$part_content .= "<script>
var map = L.map('mapid').fitWorld();

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href=\"http://mapbox.com\">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup(\"You are within \" + radius + \" meters from this point\").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

</script>";
```

It's the same code as in [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/example.html) maps source code.

When I go to Firefox, it partly works and on someone else's computer it works fine, when on my computer I get the error from the image I showed you.

So I can't locate on my computer to my own location, as in google maps it works perfectly and my extensions also don't seem to block that part.

---

**PHP:**

Basically this:

```
$ip  = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Gives me a random IP, because of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `REMOTE_ADDR` gives me the correct IP, but not when I use this from a different IP address then the local one... thats why I check if the proxy is not empty.

This is the full php code for the tracker:

```
$ip  = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/$ip";
$ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($data) {
    $location = json_decode($data);

    $longitude = $location->longitude;
    $latitude = $location->latitude;

    $longitude = str_replace(",", ".", $longitude);
    $latitude = str_replace(",", ".", $latitude);
}
```

---

My current problem is:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDE‌​D_FOR'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Which gets the correct IP address, but it almost seems like it gets the IP hosts location. Which is not my intention, I intend to get the clients location through the IP address, which currently isn't working.

I tried and tried, but couldn't seem to figure this out and hope you guys know more about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you didn't visit the URL in the error message?  It's a Chrome security thing, try running off a local webserver or getting a https certificate on your remote server.

> The Chrome Security team and I propose that, for new and particularly
> powerful web platform features, browser vendors tend to prefer to make
> the the feature available only to secure origins by default.

[...]

> Definitions:
>
> “Secure origins” are origins that match at least one of the following
> (scheme, host, port) patterns:
>
> (https, *, *)
>
> (wss, *, *)
>
> (*, localhost, *) (*, 127/8, *)
>
> (*, ::1/128, *)
>
> (file, *, —)
>
> (chrome-extension, *, —)
>
> This list may be incomplete, and may need to be changed.

Source: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

Comment: I am not running from localhost, I am running from a server currently. Currently it's on http://dev.lentesco.nl/

Comment: Sorry, I misread the definition of "secure origins".  Often these sort of errors are problems with locally running scripts, especially if they are opened as files rather than served.  In this case though it says https is required for non-local, if you run a server on localhost or open it as a file, according to the list, you should see it working on http.  Have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: `if you run a server on localhost or open it as a file, according to the list, you should see it working on http.` Could you explain this in further detail, so I could see how to implement it in the website?

NOTE: http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/example.html on this website the tracker also doesn't work for me... so I suppose its somewhere internal in my device?

Comment: Nope, I get the same error there.  Note if you click "(i)" where "http" of "https" would be in the URL it says "your connection to this site is not private".  It is not something which can be "implemented into the website".... the problem is to do with the transport protocol not being classified as "secure" by Google Chrome; they have decided as a vendor not to allow the JavaScript Location API over connections they consider unsecure.  You will need to buy a https certificate for the live version.  In the meantime you can develop on a local server, search "set up local PHP server".

Comment: Note, this doesn't have anything to do with PHP though.  If you don't need PHP you can use any server.

Comment: we have a https certificate, but it would take a long time to transfer http to https, so that's why we wanted to try the PHP code of tracking through IP address, instead of the javascript tracking one

Answer (score 1):

To get a client public ip address, in PHP 5.3 or greater use:

```
<?php

    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
        getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
        getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
        getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
        getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
        getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

?>
```

And if that is not working, use an external provider like https://geolocation-db.com

A **JSON-P** callback example:

```
<?php

    $jsonp = file_get_contents('https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp');
    $data = jsonp_decode($jsonp);

    print $data->IPv4 . '<br>';

    print $data->country_code . '<br>';
    print $data->country_name . '<br>';
    print $data->state . '<br>';
    print $data->city . '<br>';
    print $data->postal . '<br>';
    print $data->latitude . '<br>';
    print $data->longitude . '<br>';

    // Strip callback function name and parenthesis
    function jsonp_decode($jsonp) { 
        if($jsonp[0] !== '[' && $jsonp[0] !== '{') { 
           $jsonp = substr($jsonp, strpos($jsonp, '('));
        }
        return json_decode(trim($jsonp,'();'));
    }
?>
```

And a **JSON** example:

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('https://geolocation-db.com/json');
    $data = json_decode($json);

    print $data->country_code . '<br>';
    print $data->country_name . '<br>';
    print $data->state . '<br>';
    print $data->city . '<br>';
    print $data->postal . '<br>';
    print $data->latitude . '<br>';
    print $data->longitude . '<br>';
    print $data->IPv4 . '<br>';

?>
```

Comment: I get an unexpected `':'` when I use the first one and the second one says that `jsonp_decode` isn't a function, but it does look like I could use it if I understand better what the code means.

Comment: Very strange, all this code works perfectly over here. I added a json example.

Comment: Ok, this time I used the other provider you suggested, but it still links towards the IP provider of this current address, but it does get the correct IP address, which I already stumbled on xD but it's a different way to get there +1

Comment: Ok, I figured out the server of the company is actually in another place, so their IP address is there as well, basically what I wrote should work and yours probably as well if the IP address was hosted at the current address.

Comment: For now I will give the bounty to you, because your external provider gave me the correct IP address, that is how I figured it out, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with a PHP function I did a `leaflet` function instead, which tracks the user through the browser.

Using the library: [leaflet.locate](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol)

Where then I could use the:

```
// create control and add to map
var lc = L.control.locate().addTo(map);

// request location update and set location
lc.start();
```

But this isn't the answer to the PHP part of my code, even though this leaflet function also works for now.

Sadly the PHP part can't find the exact address through the IP if the server is at another place, but the leaflet way of doing it through the browser does work. Hope you guys find use in these answers.